# Phone Number formatting using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

I have an unformatted phone number (guaranteed to be 10 digits) and an unformatted extension (could be null, blank or any number of numbers). I need to put them together into a "friendly" string. I thought I'd concatenate them, then format the concatenation using a Regex.Replace. Here's the unit test I'm using to try various regexes before I plug one in:

```
    [Test, Ignore("Sandbox, does not test production code")]
    public void TestPhoneRegex()
    {
        string number = "1234567890";
        string extension = "";

        var formattedContactNumber =
            Regex.Replace("{0} x{1}".FormatWith(number, extension),
                          @"^(\d{3})[ -]?(\d{3})[ -]?(\d{4})( x\d+)?",
                          @"$1-$2-$3$4");

        Debug.WriteLine("{0} x{1}".FormatWith(number, extension));
        Debug.WriteLine(formattedContactNumber);

        Assert.AreEqual("123-456-7890", formattedContactNumber);
    }
```

The expected formatted string is the formatted phone number, without the "x" and extension. However, the last capture group is matching the "x" with or without a number behind it, so instead of "123-456-7890" I get "123-456-7890 x". This is the last bit of development that needs to be tied down before a release. Help?

Comment: Remove the x from the group? `(x \d+)?` becomes `[\sx]*?(\d+)?`

Comment: When you wrote *exception*, you meant *extension*, right?

Comment: Why would you format them *after* concatenation?

Comment: use expresso from http://www.ultrapico.com/ to test it out, hth

Comment: Why format a phone number that has no extension w/o using a different template?

Comment: I hate these phone number formatting things, because they always assume that everyone's number has the same number of digits (Nope!) in the same pattern (Nope!)

Comment: @Donal, very true eh? Maybe he's making an app that only works in North America? The numbers here are all guaranteed to be 10 digits (excluding the country code and including the area code).

Comment: @John: Well it's going to fail horribly in other markets, and the users of the application are going to be unaware of this until it totally bites them on the ass. (It's nearly as bad as postal addresses, which are worse than phone numbers due to having even more variable structure.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x isn't matched by your regex, so it isn't replaced put of the string. Try this regex instead:

```
@"^(\d{3})[ -]?(\d{3})[ -]?(\d{4}) x(\d*)
```

In the new regex `x` *isn't optional* - it will always be there according to your code (If you do want it to be optional you can use `?x?(\d*)`). Also, we're using `\d*`, so make sure the last group will always match, even when it's empty.

Comment: This was the problem; because the end of the string was not matched, it was left untouched during replacement. I solved it a slightly different way, adding an uncaptured .*$ to indicate that I wanted to match (and replace) the whole string whether I captured the optional parts or not.

Answer (score 13):

I love regular expressions, don't get me wrong, but this does not seem like a useful area to apply them. All you are doing is adding dashes to a string of 10 numbers then adding an optional "x" followed by an extension. Simpler is better.

```
public static String beautifyPhoneNumber(String number, String extension)
{
    String beautifulNumber = number.Substring(0, 3) + "-" +
                             number.Substring(3, 3) + "-" +
                             number.Substring(6, 4);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(extension))
    {
        beautifulNumber += " x" + extension;
    }
    return beautifulNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is maybe not a direct answer to your question, but possibly helpful... We use this pattern:

```
public const string NorthAmericanPhonePattern = @"^(\+?(?<NatCode>1)\s*[-\/\.]?)?(\((?<AreaCode>\d{3})\)|(?<AreaCode>\d{3}))\s*[-\/\.]?\s*(?<Number1>\d{3})\s*[-\/\.]?\s*(?<Number2>\d{4})\s*(([xX]|[eE][xX][tT])\.?\s*(?<Ext>\d+))*$";
```

And then reformat with:

```
private static string PhoneNumberMatchEvaluator(Match match)
{
    // Format to north american style phone numbers "0 (000) 000-0000"
    //                                          OR  "(000) 000-0000"
    Debug.Assert(match.Success);
    if (match.Groups["NatCode"].Success)
    {
        return match.Result("${NatCode} (${AreaCode}) ${Number1}-${Number2}");
    }
    else
    {
        return match.Result("(${AreaCode}) ${Number1}-${Number2}");
    }
}

private static string FormatPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
{
    var regex = new Regex(NorthAmericanPhonePattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return regex.Replace(phoneNumber, new MatchEvaluator(PhoneNumberMatchEvaluator));
}
```

Note: In our case we have included the national code if they did, you could easily take that out. We have also not included the extension in there - as we shift it out and put into a different field if we find it.